# C++ mutex lock declared within or outside for-loop

Tags: c++, multithreading

Given n, below code aims to print "foo", "bar" alternatively.

```
For example,
Input: n = 2
Output: "foobarfoobar"
Explanation: "foobar" is being output 2 times.
```

detailed code is listed here. There are two questions:

1) Which one is better, declaring mutex lock outside or inside for-loop?

2) When we declare mutex lock outside the for-loop, why we can NOT call `lock.unlock()` before `cv.notify_one();`. It produces runtime error!

````
class FooBar {
private:
    mutex m;
    condition_variable cv;
    int n;
    bool flag = false; // for foo printed

public:
    FooBar(int n) {
        this->n = n;
    }

    void foo(function<void()> printFoo) {

//question: can we put here? unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(m); //question: why shall this lock be declared again and again in each for-loop?

            cv.wait(lock, [&](){ return !flag; });

            // printFoo() outputs "foo". Do not change or remove this line.
            printFoo();
            flag = true;

            //question: can we call lock.unlock()? yes, it works b/c each for-loop iteration grabs a new lock! if we declare lock outside for-loop, then we can NOT unlock here? why?
            lock.unlock();

            cv.notify_one();
        }
    }

    void bar(function<void()> printBar) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);

            cv.wait(lock, [&](){ return flag; });  //wait until lambda returns true

            // printBar() outputs "bar". Do not change or remove this line.
            printBar();
            flag = false;

            lock.unlock();
            cv.notify_one();
        }
    }
};```
````

Comment: Not sure if this is the best approach, but I think of it as *does an iteration take long or not?*. If the code in your iterations does nothing expensive, then locking the mutex before the loop and unlocking it after may be less expensive then locking and unlocking for every iteration.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter where you define `unique_lock` (inside or outside loop).
All what you need to do is to ensure that `mutex` is locked when `condition_variable::wait` is called.

You got runtime error, because when you define `unique_lock` outside loop

```
unique_lock<mutex> lock(m); // mutex is LOCKED
for (int ...) {
    cv.wait(); // problem is here at second iteratio
    lock.unlock();
    cv.notify_one();
}
```

mutex is locked only in first iteration of *for* (it was locked in ctor of `unique_lock`).
In second iteration `wait` is called with unlocked lock, since c++14 it leads `std::terminate` to be called (
you can read about this behaviour [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait)).

`unique_lock` has overloaded constructor taking `std::defer_lock_t` type tag.
When this ctor is called passed mutex is not being locked. Then when you want to "open" critical section 
on given mutex you need to call explicitly `lock` function.

So, the two versions below do the same thing:

1)

```
unique_lock<mutex> lock(m, std::defer_lock); // mutex is un-locked
for ()
{
    lock.lock();
    cv.wait(...); // LOCK is locked
    lock.unlock();
    cv.notify_one();
}
```

2)

```
for ()
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(m); // is locked
    cv.wait();
    lock.unlock();
    cv.notify_one();
}
```